# Displaying a list of strings in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently making some exercises regarding displaying some tables in ASP.NET application. I Have following model class:

```
public class DynamoDB
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetOsman { get; set; }
}
```

and controller class:

```
public class DynamoController : Controller
{

    // --- THIS PART IS UPDATED ---
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DynamoDB model = new DynamoDB();
        model.GetOsman = LoadAI();
        return View(model);
    }

    public List<string> LoadAI()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Testing");
        list.Add("MCV");
        list.Add("Project");
        return list;
    }
}
```

and finally my Razor file:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@model FinalApplication.Models.DynamoDB

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Home Monitoring Application</h1>
</div>


@foreach (var item in Model.GetOsman)
{
    <text>
        @item
    </text>
}
```

But it still returns the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at following line:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GetOsman)
```

I made a similar post yesterday, since I got the same error when I was accessing the data from a DynamoDB table, but I'm getting the same error even with this simple example. My solution explorer look like this:

[image]

Comment: if you pass into view the model you have just to iterate to it, @foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: Change `return View(model.GetOsman);` to `return View(model);` You need to send the complete model.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even though I have modified to return View(model);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass your `model` to the view, not `model.GetOsman`.

```
return View(model);
```

Also, create `Dynamo` folder under `Views` and include `Index.cshtml` there.

Comment: Yes and I still can't figure out why. From the picture above, I have an Index.cshtml file in both "Home" and "Status" folder. That might be the cause of the issue perhaps ?

Comment: Try creating `Dynamo` folder and putting and `Index.cshtml` there

Answer (score 3):

The object that you're passing to `View()` is `model.GetOsman` instead of `model`.

Do this:

```
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your view expects DynamoDB model,
but you  are passing

```
 return View(model.GetOsman);
```

Try passing model to your view

```
 return View(model);
```